# How to change the default Preview code on Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I want to change the default preview code that comes when you create a new SwiftUI file in Xcode.
Change this:

```swift
#Preview {
    View()
}
```

to

```swift
struct View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        View()
    }
}
```

Honestly, I have no idea where to start. I tried the normal settings but with no luck. I'm hoping someone more experienced (you?) could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial to create custom templates](https://www.kodeco.com/26582967-xcode-project-and-file-templates)

Comment: I just want to get the default Preview Provider back; not make a new template.

Comment: Then you might have to edit the default template. By the way it's a pretty bad idea to name the default view `View`. It could interfere with the protocol.

Comment: I was just using `View()` for the example.